# How to check if a database exists in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

What is the ideal way to check if a database exists on a SQL Server using TSQL? It seems multiple approaches to implement this.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

From a Microsoft's script:

```
DECLARE @dbname nvarchar(128)
SET @dbname = N'Senna'

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.databases 
WHERE ('[' + name + ']' = @dbname 
OR name = @dbname)))
```

Comment: That may be from a Microsoft script but it's not Microsoft recommended practice.  They encourage using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views rather than directly accessing the system tables.

Comment: shouldn't "NOT EXISTS" just be "EXISTS"

Comment: why is encourage using INFORMATION_SCHEMA instead of directly using references to tables?

Comment: In general it's because Microsoft commits to the format INFORMATION_SCHEMA, and reserves the right to change the system tables as they please.  But in this case, after looking more closely, INFORMATION_SCHEMA doesn't work, so this is probably the best option.

Comment: right from my SQL Server 2005 online docs: REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS (Transact-SQL) This feature has changed from earlier versions of SQL Server. For more information, see Behavior Changes to Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: I would rather use the less verbose and more abstracted sys.(dot)databases, which is a system view, not table.  See below.

Comment: I agree INFORMATION_SCHEMA is preferred for checking objects ~inside a database.  But can INFORMATION_SCHEMA to used to check for the db itself?  <<<<<    ...............  CHECK_CONSTRAINTS  Check Constraints
COLUMN_DOMAIN_USAGE  Every column that has a user-defined data type.
COLUMN_PRIVILEGES  Every column with a privilege granted to or by the current user in the current database.
COLUMNS  Lists every column in the system
CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE  Every column that has a constraint defined on it.
CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE  Every table that has a constraint defined on it.

Comment: DOMAIN_CONSTRAINTS  Every user-defined data type with a rule bound to it.
DOMAINS  Every user-defined data type.
KEY_COLUMN_USAGE  Every column that is constrained as a key
PARAMETERS  Every parameter for every user-defined function or stored procedure in the database. For functions this returns one row with return value information.
REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS  Every foreign constraint in the system.a
ROUTINE_COLUMNS  Every column returned by table-valued functions.
ROUTINES  Every stored procedure and function in the database.
SCHEMATA  Every database in the system.

Comment: TABLE_CONSTRAINTS  Every table constraint.
TABLE_PRIVILEGES  Every table privilege granted to or by the current user.
TABLES  Every table in the system.     ...........  From http://haacked.com/archive/2006/07/05/bulletproofsqlchangescriptsusinginformation_schemaviews.aspx  (but wanted to list the information here in case the URL possibly dies sometime in the future).
VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE  Every column used in a view definition.
VIEW_TABLE_USAGE  Every table used in a view definition.
VIEWS  Every View

Comment: @mwigdahl - Please provide a reference for this claimed recommended practice.

Comment: Here are a couple of links:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx ("Information schema views provide an internal, system table-independent view of the SQL Server metadata. Information schema views enable applications to work correctly although significant changes have been made to the underlying system tables. The information schema views included in SQL Server comply with the ISO standard definition for the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.")  Also, the more strongly-worded older version:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933204%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: The answer seems to be way. INFORMATION_SCHEMA is only for within a database (so if you already know it exists). Unless @mwigdahl can provide one.

Answer (score 611):

Actually, it's best to use:

```
IF DB_ID('dms') IS NOT NULL
   --code mine :)
   print 'db exists'
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/db-id-transact-sql and note that this does not make sense with the Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Well it's certainly shorter and more cryptic.  Out of curiosity, why is it better?

Comment: Presumably because db_id is safer than checking for a database name in a specific location in `[master]`

Comment: Well, yeah, plus that it is nearly impossible for db_id() to be worse (could be the same complexity/cost) than the accepted answer since db_id queries for a number. So I rather bet on db_id() being implemented in a smarter way, since it was done by the database developers.

Comment: If you have permission issues, like you don't have permission to access [master] this works well!

Comment: Not sure this works in all cases... I tried it and it gave incorrect results so I wrote a quick test: use [X] go 

if db_id('[X]') IS NULL
 print 'db does not exist'                                                                                                          When I ran this I found that the db_id call seems to always return null.

Comment: Don't see how it could not work, given official documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186274.aspx

Comment: How to check the same for a linked server?

Comment: It has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104186/sql-server-is-there-an-if-exists-test-for-a-linked-server

Comment: @MadTigger: you shouldn't include `[ ]` in your call to `db_id`; that's SQL syntax, not part of the database name.

Comment: How to do this for another server?  ie: check if `[server].[db]` exists?  The answer linked by @Eduardo still uses "if exists" syntax.

Comment: This does not work for SQL Server, Incorrect syntax near 'NULL'.

Comment: @RobyB this is for Microsoft SQL Server, and works. Let us know what you are running.

Comment: @Eduardo This Syntax doesn't work for: Microsoft SQL Server Developer (64-bit), Platform: Linux , Version: 15.0.4073.23.

Answer (score 51):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = N'YourDatabaseName')
  Do your thing...
```

By the way, this came directly from SQL Server Studio, so if you have access to this tool, I recommend you start playing with the various "Script xxxx AS" functions that are available. Will make your life easier! :)

Comment: If 'USE [Master]' is inconvenient, you can directly address the view view from any database as 'master.sys.databases'

Answer (score 10):

I like @Eduardo's answer and I liked the accepted answer. I like to get back a boolean from something like this, so I wrote it up for you guys.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DatabaseExists(@dbname nvarchar(128))
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    declare @result bit = 0 
    SELECT @result = CAST(
        CASE WHEN db_id(@dbname) is not null THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END 
    AS BIT)
    return @result
END
GO
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
select [dbo].[DatabaseExists]('master') --returns 1
select [dbo].[DatabaseExists]('slave') --returns 0
```

Answer (score 5):

**TRY THIS**

```
IF EXISTS 
   (
     SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
    WHERE name = N'New_Database'
    )
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Database Name already Exist' AS Message
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE [New_Database]
    SELECT 'New Database is Created'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if nothing else works. It's [recommended by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

```
USE tempdb;
GO
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000);
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] = N'Sales')
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = N'USE [Sales];
    ALTER DATABASE Sales SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    USE [tempdb];

    DROP DATABASE Sales;';
    EXEC (@SQL);
END;
```

Change the sales part of the code with the name of the database that you want to delete.

Answer (score -1):

```
  Public Function SQLDatabaseExist(ByVal DefaultConnectionString As String, ByVal DataBaseName As String) As Boolean
Try
    'CREATE DATABASE
    Dim SqlString As String = ""
    SqlString = "SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = N'" & DataBaseName & "') THEN CAST (1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST (0 AS BIT) END"
    Dim ExcRet As Integer = 0
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(DefaultConnectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(SqlString, connection)
        command.Connection.Open()
        ExcRet = command.ExecuteScalar()
        command.Connection.Close()
        command.Dispose()
    End Using
    Return ExcRet
Catch ex As Exception
    Return False
End Try
```

End Function

''Notice the initial catalog in the connection string must be master!
'Sample Default Connection String

```
Dim DefaultConnectionString As String = "Data Source=localhost\SQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=Master; User ID=SA; Password='123123'; MultipleActiveResultSets=false; Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096;"
```

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the original question which is 14 years old and has an accepted answer.

Comment: It is useful for other people who code vb.net