# Check if a database exist (MySQL) and if not create it in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So i want to write a php script who checks in the data base (in localhost, user="root", pass="") "data1" exists, and if is not, create it. Please thanks for any help you can give me with this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DBName;
```

Comment: i need to know in php if the data base exist, how can i?

Answer (score 11):

Check the return value of [`mysql_select_db`](https://www.php.net/mysql_select_db) - this function will return true when the database exists and can be selected - i.e., the database might exist but the current user may not have permission to access the database. This may be enough to determine in PHP if the database exists - as long as you can guarantee that the PHP MySQL database user will always have access to this database when it exists.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!mysql_select_db('mydb')) {
    echo("creating database!\n");
    mysql_query('CREATE DATABASE mydb');
    mysql_select_db('mydb');
}
```

Comment: mysql(i)_select_db is intended to only to change the default database for the connection and you already need a connection to test it. So while it may work, probably not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Send the following to mysql from your php code : 
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS YourDB;

 Documentation : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html

Comment: i need to know in php if the data base exist, how can i?

Comment: Try connecting to the database. If it succeeds the database is there. If it does not observe the error to determine the cause :)

Comment: Or you can use the method documented here as the accepted solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838978/how-to-check-if-mysql-database-exists