# find in which database the table is located

Tags: mysql

i am working in mysql. I need to find the database within which the a particular table is located. Is that possible in mysql?

Comment: How can you address the table in the first place if you don't know what database it's in? I don't understand.

Comment: i have the list of table names...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select table_name,table_schema
from information_schema.tables
where table_name = 'your_table'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know wich database you have
[How to check if mysql database exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838978/how-to-check-if-mysql-database-exists)

or do you just want to search local for devleopement?

using heidisql or mysql workbench?