# how to get mysql tables in JComboBox

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jcombobox

i am useing the following code to get only list of mysql tables and add them to the JComboBox. but what I get is only "[]" in the JComboBox! please help me with it

```
ArrayList<String> tables = new ArrayList<String>();

public ArrayList<String> tablesArray() throws SQLException
{


    ResultSet result = connecting.getMetaData().getCatalogs();

    while(result.next())
    {
        tables.add(result.getString(0));
    }

    return tables;

}

public JComboBox comboBox()
{


    JComboBox<ArrayList> combo = new JComboBox<ArrayList>();

    combo.addItem(tables);
    combo.setBounds(130,30,190,30);

    return combo;
}
```

Comment: Try printing result.getString(0) by appending System.out.println(result.getString(0)) inside the while loop to see if resultset is not empty.

Comment: unrelated: don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, ever - instead use a suitable LayoutManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete code to retrieve all tables of a database into JComboBox:

```
public JComboBox<String> comboBox() throws SQLException
{
    ResultSet rs = connecting.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, "%", null);

    ResultSetMetaData meta = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();

    int columns = meta.getColumnCount();

    while(rs.next())
    {

            String table_names = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
            combo.addItem(table_names);
    }

    combo.setBounds(130,30,190,30);
    combo.setSelectedIndex(0);
    combo.setMaximumRowCount(5);
    return combo;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ArrayList tables = new ArrayList();

is array that contains one or more Items

> combo.addItem(tables);

later you added a.m. array as Item, then output could be correct

- pass  array as constructor, more see in [JComboBox API  Constructor Summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html)
- better to create an DefaultComboBoxModel (see a.m. API) and add those Items from ResultSet to model directly

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
while(result.next())
{
    tables.add(result.getString(1));
}
```

See this question for more information: [How to check if a particular database in mysql already exists using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414596/how-to-check-if-a-particular-database-in-mysql-already-exists-using-java) or this one [how to get list of Databases "Schema" names of MySql using java JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679259/how-to-get-list-of-databases-schema-names-of-mysql-using-java-jdbc)

However I am a bit confused are you looking for database names? Or are you trying to find table names?

When using MySQL you can always query the information_Schema views for LOADS of information regarding the tables, databases columns etc.

Comment: I want to find table names

Answer (score 0):

The `getCatalogs()` method returns catalog names, not table names. I'm not sure what it will do on MySQL, since AFAIK MySQL does not have catalogs.

If you call [`DatabaseMetaData.getTables(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) and use `null` for the first param, `catalog`, it should give you all table names without narrowing the result to any catalog.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

`ResultSetMetaData meta = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();

                int columns = meta.getColumnCount();

        while(rs.next()){

                  for(int i =1; i<=columns; i++){

                  String yourValues = rs.getString(i);

                  theCombo.addItem(yourValues);

//rs is the result set for the executed query.

                  }`

Comment: this code works pretty good but it shows only list of available databases not tables in a specific database!

Comment: this code works pretty good but it shows only list of available databases not tables in a specific database! only changing the getCatalogs() function to getTables(null, null, null, new String[] {"TABLE"}) fixes the problem