# JDBC / MySQL: How to check if a database or relation exists when creating one, then print off an error if it does

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm VERY new to JDBC and am trying to work on a project for a class.  We are supposed to create a database and relations for said database.  If the database or relations already exist, we are supposed to print a message notifying the user.  I'm not really sure how to do that.  This is what I have so far for my methods:

```
    public static void createDatabase() throws Exception {
    String createString =
      "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS companydb";
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {

            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
            String username = "username";
            String password = "password";           
            Class.forName(driver);

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

      stmt = con.createStatement();
      stmt.executeUpdate(createString);
      System.out.println("Database created.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
      if (stmt != null) { stmt.close();
      }
    }
  }
```

And for creating an employee table (not all values are created yet, just a test run):

```
   public static void createEmployeeTable() throws Exception {
    String createString =
      "create table if not exists employee" + "(Fname char(32) NOT NULL, " +
     PRIMARY KEY(Fname)";
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
      Connection con = getConnection();
      stmt = con.createStatement();
      stmt.executeUpdate(createString);
      System.out.println("Employee table created.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
      if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
  }
```

Also I realize creating a table like that might not be the most efficient way to make a relation, but it's just a work in progress right now.   Thanks for any help anyone can provide!

Regardless of if the database and relations/tables already exist or not, it puts out the same output:

```
  Database created.
  Connected to database.
  Employee table created.
  Connected to database.
  Department table created.
  Connected to database.
  Project table created.
  Connected to database.
  Works_On table created.
```

Comment: So, what happens when you run that code? What does executeUpdate() return when the db/table doesn't exist? What does it return when it doesn't exist?

Comment: When I run the code, no matter if the database or relations exist or not, it puts out:

         Database created.
Connected to database.
Employee table created.
Connected to database.
Department table created.
Connected to database.
Project table created.
Connected to database.
Works_On table created.

Comment: Remove the "if not exists" and handle the exception, it is the only reliable way; or just don't care about the previous (non-)existence and leave the "if not exists" in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a particular database in mysql already exists using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414596/how-to-check-if-a-particular-database-in-mysql-already-exists-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

Break down your code to two steps.

1. Execute a select query on the table. If the table does not exist, this will definitely throw an error.
2. If the select does not throw an error you can go ahead and create the table.

Comment: Not a bad idea, I'll try that!