# DB exists using perl

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

Is there a way to check if DB exists using perl ? Its a quick and easy one. but im still getting used to perl and DB

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838978/how-to-check-if-mysql-database-exists

Comment: The alternative question [SO 838978](http://stackoverflow.com/q/838978) does not cover Perl at all; this question is specifically about Perl. This question is not a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DBI module is a popular way access and manipulate databases in perl. Here is a short example of usage of DBI which tests a connection:

```
use DBI;

$user = 'donny';
$pw = 'ppp';
$dsn = 'basetest';
$dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw) or die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

The last line could also be something more like:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:',$user.'@'.$password,$dbconnectstring);
```

Or something similar - just edit the first parameter as makes sense.

As you can see - you'll get unable to connect if the DB can't be found.

Here is the documentation relevant to DBI:
http://dbi.perl.org/docs/

Sidenote: Also, note you can access sqlplus - or any command line - within a perl script. Just use backticks. It may be worth it to check that way, if you have the tools available on the machine.