# how to check if database exist in mysql procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a procedure in mysql which is doing something with DB, but it needs to throw exception in case that it exist. How do I do that?

I need something like

```
if exist <db name> then
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45002'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'This database already exist';
end if;
```

Comment: Has been asked here before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838978/how-to-check-if-mysql-database-exists?rq=1

Comment: that question is not about implementation as if statement in a procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this SQL:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'DBName'
```

In a procedure it would then be something like this:

```
DECLARE name TEXT;
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME INTO name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'DBName'
IF name = 'DBName' THEN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45002'
   SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'This database already exist';
END IF;
```

(Disclaimer: I haven't written MySQL procedures before and I haven't tested this one. It is only mentioned to give the way of a possible implementation. Also, this example isn't complete.)

Comment: how do I implement it in procedure as if statement?

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope the syntax is correct. If anyone sees errors, please update the answer.

Comment: I suppose it's if name = 'DBName' then but this answers what I needed