# CRUD operations on a database in Play

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, anorm

I'd like to be able to create/delete/change a database and tables, create/delete indexes and all these kinds of things by Scala code, not by an sql file. Probably, using anorm. Is wonder, is it possible?

I know it's possible to do CRUD operations with tables.

Comment: You can. Give it a try. Creating\deleting tables\indexes\whatever are just SQL statements

Comment: I'd recommend reading the documentation at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaAnorm for details on how to use Anorm.  They directly cover CRUD operations.

Comment: @JasonPearson, and where is the information about creating a db there?

Comment: @Alex Anorm cannot create a database, it must already exist or else it will be unable to connect to it.  The evolutions can create/alter/drop tables, stored procedures, views, indices.  Evolutions run before Global onStart in Play.

Comment: @JasonPearson, thanks but I'd like to use scala code, not sql, like rails uses schema.rb written in ruby to create db scheme.

Answer (score 1):

[Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/) is a Scala ORM that can do most of what you're asking for, however it does not have a pure Scala way of creating a new database.  You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247742/slick-create-database).

Answer (score 1):

You say you are using play then start off using Ebean ORM

Have a look at 
[Play Persistance](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaEbean)
and 
[Avaje EBean](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/getstarted_props.html)

If you have downloaded play look in the samples directory there is a computer database example. It is a very good example of CRUD

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend slick! Slick at first seems different if you are moving from directly stating your statements, but it is super handy to work with. Check it out [here](http://slick.typesafe.com/)