# how to see if database exists with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I recently decided to switch to PDO due to the mysqli prepared statement complexity and irregularities. This was my mysqli function to test for a database:

```
public static function is_database($database) {
    self::connect();
    if( mysqli_select_db(self::$conn,$database) ) {
        self::$dbname = $database;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    self::disconnect();
}
```

The only thing I've read so far about PDO and a database of anything was this:

```
$pdo->exec("use database");
```

Which is not what I want, unless using this with a try catch would work. Something of this sort

```
public static function is_database($database){
   self::connect();
   try {
      self::$conn->exec('use '.$database);
      return true;
   } catch(PDOException $e){
     print($e->getMessage();
     return false;
     die();
   }
}
```

Need a little assistance for the 1 hour new PDO user. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: PDO doesn't include a built-in function to switch databases like mysqli.   Instead of trying to switch to the database, maybe you should be using a count(*) on a query like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838978/how-to-check-if-mysql-database-exists

Comment: I wasn't trying to switch just to see if it actual exists like what you said using count

Answer (score 5):

In accordance with the query found at [How to check if mysql database exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838978/how-to-check-if-mysql-database-exists)

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'DBName'");
return (bool) $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

We check the count which will return 1 or 0 and type cast it as an boolean (true/false).

Of course this requires an existing connection through PDO.  This wouldn't work for you to check the database before the first connection.

Comment: You can't connect with PDO without a db? ` new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;', USERNAME, PASSWORD);` and be null and it will connect??

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot.  PDO works for multiple DBMS, not just MySQL.  Not all DBMS have multiple databases you can switch between.

Comment: If you were trying to check if a database exists initially, you could just setup a try catch block during the PDO instantiation.  However, you would need to check the error message for why the connection failed.  There most likely is an error code specific to a database not existing.

Comment: I don't see many use cases for if a database exists.  Most web applications should be restricted to a single database.

Comment: well its a startup cms, the user needs to enter the db name and it checks if it is correct.

Comment: I think at that point, you could just display the PDOException message to the user if the database connection fails.

Comment: Yeah I'll have to think over the best possible solution at this point. Thanks for the information though.

Comment: You're welcome.  I added an example on the try catch with the constructor, but I think you already grasped what I was saying.

Answer (score -1):

A very simple answer execute your code in **"try-catch"** exception;
and if you want to throw an error then echo your error and if you don't then just live empty your catch block;
how useful try catchs are

1. if DB does not exist it will create
2. error of your choice or no error

the example is given below.

```
        try {
            $conn->exec($sql);
        } catch (PDOException $th) {
            echo "<br> sql error";
        }
```

Comment: There are **many** database errors. It could be Too many connections or Mysql has gone away, or [anything out of 1000s possible errors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/global-error-reference.html). You **must** compare the error message/code with the expected one.  Otherwise this code will do more harm than good. Also, `echo "<br> sql error";` makes no sense whatsoever

Comment: Yes, `echo "<br> SQL error";` make no sense because I don't want to make sense, I don't want any error. and if you want to compare then use if-else or use compare sign there are a lot of options for a lot of errors. I want to say that this is for a beginner not for professionals, `this is for checking that DB exists or not`. and ya if you wanna use a professional way then read more spend more time searching and a lot of ways to get your answer.

Comment: And yaa your source is very useful I never knew that `THANK YOU`.

Comment: "read more spend more time searching and a lot of ways to get your answer" - this is **not** how we answer questions here on Stack Overflow.