# MySQL create database if not exist

Tags: mysql

I have a T-SQL query which create database if it does not exist yet:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT name 
                FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
                WHERE ('[' + 'DBName' + ']' = 'DBName'
                   OR name = 'DBName')))
BEGIN 
    CREATE DATABASE DBName

    PRINT 'DATABASE_CREATED' 
END 
ELSE 
    PRINT 'DATABASE_EXIST'
```

When I want use this in MySQL I get an error:

> 'IF' is not valid input at this postion

I change this script as

```
IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SCHEMA_NAME 
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA 
   WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'DBName') > 0)
THEN BEGIN 
    CREATE DATABASE DBName

    PRINT 'DATABASE_CREATED'
ELSE 
    PRINT 'DATABASE_EXIST'`
```

but it still doesn't work

How can I create this query in MySQL?

Comment: You can see this SO posts too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838978/how-to-check-if-mysql-database-exists

Comment: Question re-tagged to microsoft `sql-server`

Comment: @Drew they are asking how to do it in MySQL.

Comment: @MartinSmith but look at the rest of it, `master.dbo.sysdatabases ` ... I have no clue what they are referencing other than mister softie tables

Comment: I wrote that i have that query in MSSQL

Comment: oh ok my bad. So you want this in mysql

Comment: Run SSMS as admin!

Comment: Your comment is invalid, read question to the end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the example in a helper (permanent) database. That db's name is `permanent`

One time db create:

```
create schema permanent;
```

Now make sure you

```
USE permanent;
```

then

Stored Proc:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS createDB;  
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE createDB(IN pDbName VARCHAR(100))  
BEGIN
    DECLARE preExisted INT;
    DECLARE ret VARCHAR(50);

    SET ret='DATABASE_EXIST';
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO preExisted
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
    WHERE SCHEMA_NAME=pDbName;
    IF preExisted=0 THEN
        SET @sql=CONCAT('CREATE SCHEMA ',pDbName); -- add on any other parts of string like charset etc
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt1;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
        -- right here you could assume it worked or take additional
        -- step to confirm it
        SET ret='DATABASE_CREATED';
    END IF;
    SELECT ret as 'col1';
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Test:

```
use permanent;
call createDB('xyz');
-- returns col1 DATABASE_CREATED
call createDB('xyz');
-- returns col1 DATABASE_EXIST
```

Comment: Thanks it was what i needed :)

Answer (score 113):

I'm not sure exactly how you'd check, but if you just want to create it if it doesn't exist, then you can do

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DBname
```

Comment: I know that that I can use `IF NOT EXISTS` but i need return string `'DATABASE_CREATED'` or `'DATABASE_EXIST'`

Comment: then make a stored proc out of it and pass a parameter

Comment: @Szymson It would also help if you knew what server type you have. I appears to not even be `mysql` so I retagged your question to microsoft

Comment: stored proc can be added to database but I need create database first

Comment: Right. A call to a stored proc in a helper db.