# MySQL Create table IF NOT EXISTS syntax error

Tags: mysql

I am kind of new to MySQL and i am trying to get to know the commands, and i thought starting with how to make a table might not be such a bad idear.

However, the only command i find online keeps returning a syntax error. I must be doing something wrong, do you guys see what it is?

```
CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] test (test_column date);
```

-Natan

EDIT 1:

If you downvote, please leave a reason why and be prepared to remove it if i fix it.

EDIT 2:

Stackoverflow had this question identified as a duplicate of a completely different question. so i am now required to explain why. Hereby: 
My question is about the create table statement, this persons code is much more complicated and about the IF statement.

Comment: The `[` and `]` is not valid syntax. It's probably meant to symbolise an optional argument, but you should remove them from your query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL create database if not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40333251/mysql-create-database-if-not-exist)

Comment: And @johan, Also Thank you. I feel really stupid right now.

Comment: Don't worry about it, everyone here have done similar things, it's part of being a developer :)

Comment: You may need to read up on typographical and syntax conventions in mysql documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/manual-conventions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query must looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (test_column date);
```

`[IF NOT EXISTS]` it's part which you can omit, it isn't required (that's why it is in brackets). And it means that you can run query without this part, like:

```
CREATE TABLE test (test_column date);
```

But in this case your query will fail if table `test` already exists.

Comment: I will flag this as the answer in a minute. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
    test_column date
)
```

Comment: @ThatOne, that's not required