# Do something if MySQL database exist in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using wamp server 3.0.6, mysql 5.7.14 and php 5.6.25. I am new to php.
I need a function which can check if database is exist. if not create one. if database exist execute some code.

```
$dbname = "mydb";
if($dbname exist){
   // do someting
} else {
   // create new database.
   database name = $dbname;
}
```

I know SQL command CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydb. But I don't want to use this and it doesn't work on my application.

Comment: Why doesn't it work for your application?

Comment: As I said I am new to php and mysql. I don't know how to use squl command to get my work done with php.

Comment: Are you going to gave a different database from which you can fire SQL and check some other database?

Comment: no. Not like this.

Comment: So you want to check if the database you are going to connect exists or not?

Comment: Yes. But not in mysql command CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if mysql database exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838978/how-to-check-if-mysql-database-exists)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'mydb'
```

And in php something like:

```
<?php

    $connection;
    $dbname = 'mydb'
    $username = 'username';
    $password = "password";

    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost", $username, $password);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

    $stmt = connection->prepare("SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME =:dbname");
    $stmt->execute(array(":dbname"=>$dbname));
    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
    {
        echo 'db exists';
        // or do other stuff    
    }
    else { echo 'db does not exist'; }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. can u give me a function how to use this MySQL command in php?

Comment: I don't use PDO. I use mysqli.

Comment: @Kurt OP doesn't know if the database exists or not let alone fire your SQL

Comment: Indeed, changed it.

Comment: I don't know how to change it.