# How to check DB existence using PDO and IF else statement only in PHP

Tags: php, database, pdo

I want to **check if a database exists or not using PDO only**(if available). Also, if it's not possible, **please provide me a quick solution on how to check database existence using if else statement**. *Any help is appreciated. Thank You!*

Here's what I have done so far:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost", "root", "");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //Now since I have been connected, I want to check DB existence.
    if(DB exists)
    {
        //check table existence
    }
    else {
        //Create DB
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if mysql database exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838978/how-to-check-if-mysql-database-exists)

Comment: No actually this is done with mysql_* which is deprecated in php 7. I want to use PDO only as PDO supports other tyeps of databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost", "root", "");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //Now since I have been connected, I want to check DB existence.
    $databases = $conn->query('show databases')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    if(in_array(YOUR_DATABASE_NAME,$databases))
    {
        //check table existence
    }
    else {
        //Create DB
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thank You! I found this extremely helpful! :)