# Java Spring Boot creating a MySQL database at application startup

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am new in Java Spring.
I created the default project by adding dependencies. Now I want the **Weather database** to be created when the application is launched, if it does not exist on the computer.I am using a mysql database.

*How do I achieve this because I get errors when I launch the application?*

*and another question: is it possible to achieve that without explicitly specifying the username and password from the database?*

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'weather'
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/weather?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Comment: Did you try to connect with MySQL workbench and looked if the database lis there?

Comment: of course. If I first create a database through the console and then try to connect to it in the application, then everything works. But how do I make sure that the database is created automatically when the application is launched?

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838978/how-to-check-if-mysql-database-exists to see if the database exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good idea could be to use Test containers. All you need to do is run docker. Springboot will handle the rest. It will automatically create and connect to the database without needing to know the username and password are. For my project I am using Postgres and the setup for MySql is the same. You will need to install the dependency for it.

```
@TestConfiguration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class TestContainersConfig {

    @Bean
    @ServiceConnection
    PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer() {
        return new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:15");
    }
}
```

I am using this for tests, so I run my application with a new database by doing the following:

```
public class TestEchoBoardApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.from(EchoBoardApplication::main)
            .with(TestContainersConfig.class)
            .run(args);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into flyway to handle your database migrations. Its a tool which executes sql scripts on startup.

https://flywaydb.org/