# Is there an "IF EXISTS" test for a linked server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I want to be able to programmatically (in T-SQL) check if a specific linked server already exists for my current server and database (so that if the link doesn't exist yet, I can create it). I tried stuff like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('myserver\devdb_1') IS NULL
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Does not exist, need to create link'
  EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'myserver\devdb_1', 
                                     @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'
END
ELSE
  PRINT 'Link already exists'
```

But the OBJECT_ID test always returns null, even if the link already exists.  Any way to do this check in T-SQL, so that the rest of my code can assume the link always exists?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Check in [`sys.servers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-servers-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
if not exists(select * from sys.servers where name = N'myserver\devdb_1')
```

Comment: +  and is_linked = 1

Answer (score 28):

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT TOP (1) * FROM sysservers WHERE srvname = 'myserver\devdb_1' )
```

Comment: Essentially, nearly the same answer as Remus Rusanu, I up-voted you both, but gave him the check for including the link. ;-)

Comment: Interesting. What's the diff between `sysservers` and `sys.servers`. I noticed that the column names are different!

Comment: @seebiscuit The first is a table and considered 'the old way', the second is a system view which is the recommended approach. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/mapping-system-tables-to-system-views-transact-sql