# Return Zero when Open query returns error

Tags: sql

Select * from openQuery(XYZ,'abc');

The query executes correctly if the linked server is available. I want to display zero if the linked server is down. Is there any way I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try / catch statement. Explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx).

Comment: I tried it and it gives the same error if connection is lost.

Comment: Try catch along with the function to check the linked server helped me . The function to check the linked server connection is available in the link below               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104186/sql-server-is-there-an-if-exists-test-for-a-linked-server