# Can the INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema be used to check if a database exists?

Tags: sql

There are [alternative ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679000/how-to-check-if-a-database-exists-in-sql-server) to detect database existence, but can the INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema be used instead (such as in the master db, or somewhere else)?

Comment: Any particular reason why? Are you looking for something more portable than the SQL Server `sys` views?

Comment: No particular reason other than curiosity to know if there is a more portable/supported way of doing it. Seems strange that INFORMATION_SCHEMA would be created for this purpose but not cover this case.

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is intended to cover details on a *per-database* level, not anything outside of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible with INFORMATION_SCHEMA. As noted in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx), INFORMATION_SCHEMA is created on a per database basis, and contains metadata specific to the database it is created in. There is no concept of a "server level" INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yours and Joe's are both correct and say essentially the same thing, so I tossed a coin and you won. Marked as correct.

Comment: @TimPartridge: Glad to help. In general, I think most people use "first to answer" as a tie breaker, rather than a coin toss. Either method yields the same result in this case. :-)

Answer (score 2):

No; as you can see from all of the views defined in the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) namespace, the views contained therein are specific to a single database, so nothing database-agnostic (such as a list of databases) is provided. You'll have to use the ordinary system views as described in your linked question/answer to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yours and Joe's are both correct and say essentially the same thing, so I tossed a coin and you lost. Accepting Joe's answer as correct. Sorry ;)