# how to check if a database exist?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, delphi, database-connection, delphi-7

I'm trying to connect to databases in sql server 2008 using delphi 7. I have an array `arr_foo` that contains the names of databases. this is what my script looks like:

```
for i:=3 to 5 do begin
  sql := 'SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '+quotedstr(arr_foo[i]);
  adoquery1.close;
  adoquery1.sql.text := sql;
  adoquery1.open;
  if not adoquery1.isempty then begin
    adoconnection1.close;
    adoconnection1.defaultdatabase := arr_foo[i];
    adoconnection1.open;
  end;
end;
```

at first, adoquery1 is already connected to adoconnection1. adoconnection1 is connected to //192.168.5.211 (which is my server).

the problem is that when I run the above script on delphi 7, it returns an error 'Property value is invalid. Please make sure the value is typed correctly' and stops at 'adoquery1.open' but when I run the query `SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'mydb3'` in SQL SERVER Management Studio 2008 it returns 1 record normally. what is wrong with my script?

Comment: In SQL server when you login to your server with management studio you automatically connect to the "master" database, that's why the query works. I don't think adoconnection does that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a database exists in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679000/how-to-check-if-a-database-exists-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `DB_ID` function -

```
IF DB_ID('AdventureWorks2008R2') IS NOT NULL
    PRINT 'exists'
```

Change query on this:

```
sql := 'SELECT ID = DB_ID(' + quotedstr(arr_foo[i]) + ')';
```

And check that ID value is not null.

Comment: thanks. this solves it. since no one else has answered, I'll flag this as the correct answer.