# Wait before accessing a database created programmatically?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm creating a database in my program using SqlClient.  The app requires a new database to be created periodically, but the structure is the same.  So I have the create script in a file, and I execute it one line at a time.  When I'm done, I just close it up, because another part of the app (written using SubSonic) will then manipulate the newly created database.

The problem I'm having is that even after successfully creating the database, when I go to access it I get an exception, telling me the Login failed.  Some time later, this access succeeds.  I've narrowed this down to 5 seconds - anything less causes the failure, at 5 seconds it works fine.  The code below demonstrates that (in a kind of contrived way), but it also proved to me that SubSonic wasn't involved in the issue at all.

Is this something I just need to put up with, or is there something I'm not doing quite right?

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace SqlConnTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new ContentDB();
        if (x.IsNew)
        {
            x.Dispose();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4500);
            Console.WriteLine("Second time around");
            x = new ContentDB();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("All done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class ContentDB : IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {

            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }
    public bool IsNew {get;set;}


    public ContentDB()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Arch;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Brunner;Password=Brunn3r1x");
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Arch database needs to be created. {0}", ex.Message);
            IsNew = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        if (IsNew)
            CreateDB();
    }

    private void CreateDB()
    {
        using (var SqlScriptReader = new StreamReader("c:\\temp\\create.sql"))
        {
            var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Brunner;Password=Brunn3r1x");
            conn.Open();
            string SqlCmd = SqlScriptReader.ReadLine();
            while (SqlCmd != null && SqlCmd != String.Empty)
            {
                try
                {
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlCmd,conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SQL command {0} failed,\n{1}", SqlCmd,ex.Message);
                }
                SqlCmd = SqlScriptReader.ReadLine();
            }
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("CreateDB finished");
    }

}
```

}

And the contents of the .SQL file are:

```
USE [master]
CREATE DATABASE [Arch] ON  PRIMARY ( NAME = N'Arch', FILENAME = N'C:\temp\Arch.mdf', SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) LOG ON ( NAME = N'Arch_log', FILENAME = N'C:\temp\Arch_log.ldf'  , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
USE [Arch]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RptContent] ([RptContentID]    [int]     IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,   [RptContentBLOB]  [varbinary](max)        NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_RptContent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RptContentID] ASC ) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I run it with no Arch database existing, I get:

```
Arch database needs to be created. Cannot open database "Arch" requested by the
login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'Brunner'.
CreateDB finished
Second time around
Arch database needs to be created. Cannot open database "Arch" requested by the
login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'Brunner'.
SQL command CREATE DATABASE [Arch] ON  PRIMARY ( NAME = N'Arch', FILENAME = N'C:
\temp\Arch.mdf', SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) LOG
ON ( NAME = N'Arch_log', FILENAME = N'C:\temp\Arch_log.ldf'  , SIZE = 1024KB , M
AXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%) failed,
Database 'Arch' already exists. Choose a different database name.
SQL command CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RptContent] ([RptContentID]    [int]     IDENTIT
Y(1,1) NOT NULL,   [RptContentBLOB]  [varbinary](max)        NOT NULL CONSTRAINT
[PK_RptContent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RptContentID] ASC ) WITH (PAD_INDEX  =
OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] failed,
There is already an object named 'RptContent' in the database.
CreateDB finished
All done
```

Running it with a sleep of 5000 gives me:

```
Arch database needs to be created. Cannot open database "Arch" requested by the
login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'Brunner'.
CreateDB finished
Second time around
All done
```

And running if the Arch database already exists gives:

```
All done
```

Sorry if this is long - I tried to strip it down to the short version of the code that would demonstrate what I'm doing and the problem.

Comment: because that's how long it takes to zero out the transaction log on disk (and possibly the data file if instant data file initialisation is not turned on). It will vary on the size of the database files

Comment: Thanks - knowing that it's just a fact of life helps.  Now I can just concentrate on a reasonable implementation of waiting instead of trying to find something wrong with what I was doing...

Answer (score 0):

Instead a thread sleep, you could make this task: Create a loop that searches for created database, and loops while you can't find it.

How to find if a database exists: [How to check if a database exists in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679000/how-to-check-if-a-database-exists-in-sql-server)

For performance purpose, you should put a timer (like a thread sleep) for each loop, instead searching continuously. You said that average time is 5 seconds, so looping at each 1s or 2s might be fine!