# C# is showing variable before database results returned

Tags: c#

I am trying to show data from a database, but it seems like C# is creating an empty result set, and showing *that* before my results from the database are able to populate the variable:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
@{
    WebMatrix.Data.Database DB = WebMatrix.Data.Database.Open(MyConString);
    var data = DB.Query("SELECT * FROM MyTable");
}

<div>
    <p>
        @foreach (var d in data)
        {
            <a href="@d.url">@d.name</a>
        }
    </p>
</div>
```

On an initial load of the application I get this:

```
<div>
    <p>
    </p>
</div>
```

However, if I reload the page, I get the expected results:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <a href="home">Home</a>
        <a href="contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="faq">FAQ</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

How do I force the compiler to wait for the results?

---

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884357/wait-before-accessing-a-database-created-programmatically), but it basically says to loop over the results until results are returned. But it's possible for there to be no results at all, so that won't work.

Comment: I don't think this is what's happening here, that function is synchronous. Are you inserting the items later or something? Either way, I'd look into other reasons for your results, possibly implementing only this code in an otherwise empty application.

Comment: This looks like MVC but you are getting data in the view instead of the controller?

Comment: @Blindy No, the data is already in the database, I don't insert it here - on the fly - or anything. However, the `WebMatrix.Data.Database` variable is created in a Model elsewhere - I did not include this for brevity's sake. Do you think that could be causing it to unsynch?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, but it's possible. I'm just saying your initial conclusion is wrong in this case, the call is synchronous.

Comment: There is almost certainly something that we cannot see here, another part of the code that is important. Is the connection string specified correctly? Where does it come from?

Comment: In the model, where the WebMatrix DB is built, there is logic to determine which connection string to use based on the environment (Local, Dev, etc). There is also logic in the Layout.cshtml that checks to see if the user has permission to be on that page. Both of those require DB calls, and they're all created with the same model WebMatrix DB logic. Could that be causing the issue? ALSO, the connection strings are 100% correct, and work perfectly in every other scenario.

Answer (score -2):

Please change

```
var data = DB.Query("SELECT * FROM MyTable");
```

to

```
var myQuery= "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
```

and then your foreach change to

```
@foreach(var row in db.Query(myQuery))
```

This will work.

Comment: And why does that fix the problem?

Comment: Travis, I thin you are missing something else. Please look here:
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/146/webmatrix-a-first-application