# How do I check the existance of a database in SQL Server on AWS RDS?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Normally to see all the databases in a SQL Server, you can use:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT name 
            FROM master.dbo.databases 
            WHERE 'myDB' = @dbname 
               OR name = @dbname)))
```

[previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679000/how-to-check-if-a-database-exists-in-sql-server)

But in AWS RDS, I get this error:

> Invalid object name 'master.dbo.databases'

Is there another place to look up the databases in AWS RDS? By default there is always `rdsadmin` and then anything else the user adds.

Comment: Interesting that that's the accepted answer, because `master.dbo.databases` will not work on any installation of SQL Server -- not any recent version, at least. `sys.databases` is another matter.

Comment: I seems like `master.sys.sysdatabases` is what I am looking for. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Technically it's unnecessary to add `master`; there's only one `sys.databases` and its contents will not change by adding a database (nor is any database capable of declaring its own `sys.databases`). I also don't know if an RDS-hosted server works the same as an on-premise server -- all I know is that `master.dbo.databases` is right out.